# How to apply backpressure to Tcl output channel?

Tags: tcl

We have an application that allows a user to pass an arbitrary Tcl code block (as a callback) to a custom API that invokes it on individual elements of a large data tree. For performance, this is done using a thread pool, so things can get ripping.

The problem is, we have no control over user code, and in one case they are doing a puts  that causes memory to explode and the app to crash. I can prevent the this by redirecting stdout to /dev/null which leads me to believe that Tcl's internal buffers can't be emptied fast enough, so it keeps buffering. Heap analysis seems to confirm this.

[image: Massif Heap Analysis]

What I don't understand is that I haven't messed with any of stdout's options, so it should be line buffered, blocking, 4k. So, my first question would be: why is this happening? Shouldn't there already be backpressure applied to prevent this?

My second question would be: how do I prevent this? If the user wants to to something stupid, I'm more than willing to throttle their performance, but I don't want the app to crash. I suppose one solution would be to redefine puts to write to a file (or simply do nothing) before the callback is invoked, but I'd be interested if there was a way to ensure backpressure on the channel to prevent it from continuing to buffer.

Thanks for any thoughts!

Comment: What's consuming the channel in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the channel type and how you've configured it. However, the normal model is that writes to a *synchronous* channel (`-blocking true`) will either buffer or write immediately (according to the `-buffering` option) and writes to an *asynchronous* channel (`-blocking false`) will, if not processed immediately, be queued to be carried out later by an internal event handler. For most applications, that does the right thing; it sounds like you've passed an asynchronous channel to code that doesn't call into the event loop (or at least not frequently). Try `chan configure`ing the channel to be synchronous before starting the user code; you're in a separate thread so the blocking behaviour shouldn't be a problem for the rest of the application.

Some channels are more tricky. The one that people most normally encounter is the console channel in Tk on platforms such as Windows, where the channel ends up writing into a widget that doesn't have a maximum number of retained lines.